# Add items in another thread

Tags: android, json, orm, retrofit

I have a fragment where I post request to server. Because of offline mode in my app, I am using database where I store objects and then I set them to recyclerView.

Is there another (better) way how to save data to instead of **for loop**?

> request which I post

```
 private void getContacts() {
        showProgressDialog();
        FactoryAPI.getContacts().getContacts(user.getToken()).enqueue(new Callback<ContactsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ContactsResponse> call, Response<ContactsResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    contactList = response.body().getContactsList();

                    for (int i = 0; i < contactList.size(); i++) {
                        ContactORM contact = new ContactORM();
                        contact.setId(contactList.get(i).getId());
                        contact.setName(contactList.get(i).getName());
                        contact.setLastname(contactList.get(i).getLastname());
                        contact.setEmail(contactList.get(i).getEmail());
                        contact.setPhoto(contactList.get(i).getPhoto());
                        contact.save();
                        databaseList.add(contact);
                    }

                    sortList();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    setRecyclerView();
                }
            }
```

Comment: why not use the same class for parsing and DB this way you can add the list immediately to the database?

Comment: I got an exception when I extended that class, so i think that there was problem with parsing.

Answer (score 0):

[SugarORM](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/) is a good library. Otherwise I don't think you can do anything regarding for-loop. I have not used SugarORM so don't know much about it.